# Can't downcast Swift objects to protocols -- what to do?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write an extension method to Array similar to NSArray's `containsObject` method. Here's what I tried:

```
extension Array {
    func contains(item: T) -> Bool {
        for value in self {
            if item == value {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

I get an error on the line `if item == value {` that says:

```
"Could not find an overload for "==" that accepts the supplied arguments."
```

I tried casting item and value to Equatable before the comparison, but it's not possible to downcast a non-objc object to a protocol

```
var equatableItem = item as Equatable
```

The error message is:

```
"Cannot downcast from 'T' to non-@objc protocol type 'Equatable'"
```

How would one implement this method in Swift? I'm not interested in using `bridgeToObjectiveC` and calling containsObject; this is more of an academic question if writing a method such as this is possible in pure Swift.

Answer (score 4):

To add, `item as Equatable` doesn't work because testing conformance to protocols is only allowed for `@objc` protocols (which `Equatable` is not). See Protocols -> Checking for Protocol Conformance in the Swift Programming Language book.

> You can check for protocol conformance only if your protocol is marked
>   with the @objc attribute

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that T is already defined and the Array's definition of T does not conform to Equatable. You can either accomplish what you want by casting, and risking an invalid cast, or you could pass in a delegate where no casting would be required.

Consider modifying like so:

```
extension Array {
   func contains(comparator: (T)->Bool) -> Bool {
    for item in self {
        if comparator(item) {
           return true
        }
    }
    return false
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
class Test {
    func arrayContains(){
        var test: Int[] = [0,1,3,4,5]
        //should be true 
        var exists = test.contains({(item)->Bool in item == 0});
    }
}
```